# Display box at the bottom of div instead of top of div

Tags: html, css

I try to set my box to the bottom part of the div, but it appears on the top part of the div even I have set bottom:0px;

Here is the link of my code : [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v5wczphq/1/)

```
  <div class="container">
    <p class="box bottom0" style="background-color:grey">Category1</p>
    <p class="box bottom0" style="background-color:red">Category2</p>
    <p class="box bottom0" style="background-color:blue">Category3</p>    
  </div>
```

```
 margin: 0 auto; height: 500px;
 }
 .bottom0{
  bottom: 0px;
}
.box{
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flex` on the container

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

or

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```
.bottom0{
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

---

```css
 .container { 
 width: 960px; 
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 500px;
display: flex;
 }
 .bottom0{
  align-self: flex-end;
}
.box{
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  display:inline-block;
  
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <p class="box bottom0" style="background-color:grey">Category1</p>
    <p class="box bottom0" style="background-color:red">Category2</p>
    <p class="box bottom0" style="background-color:blue">Category3</p>    
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

the `bottom` property has no effect on statically positioned elements (elements have `position: static` by default)

you need to set a `position: relative` on the container and `position: absolute` on `.box` in order to see that property work.

Comment: it only appears box of  "category3".. i think it stack together on top of box "category 2 and category 1"..

Comment: yes, all those elements are stacked on top of each other. Use a different bottom value for each box, or place all the categories in a single box element or consider to use a different layout (flexbox or grid)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="bottom0">

    <p class="box" style="background-color:grey">Category1</p>
    <p class="box" style="background-color:red">Category2</p>
    <p class="box" style="background-color:blue">Category3</p>   
    </div>
  </div>
```

and add position:absolute in bottom0 css

```
 .bottom0{
  bottom: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: your solution works too. I wish I can accept more than 1 answer but sadly I cant.. thx for your reply. I do really appreciate your help sir